# Symbols in lib not being included

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have been updating a big working C++ Windows application in Visual Studio 2022 into several static libs.
The idea is to share part of the code to an external developer, and not share the complete C++ files of the project. Only part of the code would be shared, and the rest would be .lib's and .h's.

The structure of the entire solution is:

- External LIB
- Library 1 LIB - Referencing .h's from the External LIB
- Application EXE - Using the above libs

When building the application EXE, the link fails with thousands of errors of missing symbols from the External LIB. "LNK2001   unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: bool __thiscall ..."

```
1>Common.lib(LocalizedString.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: bool __thiscall cocos2d::Value::isNull(void)const " (__imp_?isNull@Value@cocos2d@@QBE_NXZ)
1>  Hint on symbols that are defined and could potentially match:
1>    "__declspec(dllimport) public: bool __thiscall cocos2d::Data::isNull(void)const " (__imp_?isNull@Data@cocos2d@@QBE_NXZ)
```

The EXE is configured to include all the libs (configured in VS project settings: Additional Dependencies).
All the projects are being built with __cdecl (/Gd) and Multi-threaded Debug DLL (/MDd).

If I add to the EXE code some dummy declarations of symbols that are being referred into the "unresolved external symbol" error, Visual Studio adds those symbols and I can see the number of errors decreasing. But this is not a good solution...
It looks like somehow Visual Studios is adding all the symbols automatically.

I believe this whole issue may be related with the following. When building my libs I get the following "warning LNK4006: XXXX already defined in XXXXX.lib(xxhash.obj); second definition ignored".

I have tried different project settings, like "Link Library Dependencies: Yes". But nothing seems to fix it.

I'm stuck with this for two days... Can someone save me?

Comment: It looks like the main project (exe) is trying to link with a DLL import library.  However in the project description (above) you don't mention building any DLLs.  Please list a few (5ish) of the complete error messages in the question as formatted text.

Comment: There are no DLL's. When creating static libs, the default Runtime library flag is "Multi-threaded Debug DLL (/MDd).". But this is valid for .lib's.

Comment: The `__declspec(dllimport) public:...` means that the exe project has used a header file that requires symbols exported from a DLL import library.  What symbols these are we can't tell as you don't include the full error message in the question.  These missing symbols may be part of your project, the C Runtime Support or an external project/library; again without at least one (or more) of the full error messages we can't tell.

Comment: added part of the full error messages to the post @RichardCritten

Comment: The exe is expecting an import library for the `Cocos` dll library.  If you think that you are using `Cocos` as a static library then the project setting are misconfigured.

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem. There was an hidden define in the external lib adding the dllimport to every external class.

```
#if defined(CC_STATIC)
    #define CC_DLL
#else
#if defined(_USRDLL)
    #define CC_DLL     __declspec(dllexport)
#else         /* use a DLL library */
    #define CC_DLL     __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
#endif
```